# setKeepAliveTimeout handler not called sometimes

Tags: ios, background, voip, keep-alive

I'm writing a VoIP app on iOS.I set the 'voip' and 'audio' UIBackgroundModes properties for my project and I called setKeepAliveTimeout successfully, but, sometimes, after the specified time, my app is not be waken up and the handler is not be called.However, it's OK sometimes.
Does someone met this yet?I got no clues for the reason.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787202/voip-app-is-not-wake-up-in-time-if-set-15-min-for-setkeepalivetimeout-method

Comment: it's not the same situation, my app seems never wake up once it go to background instead of waking up irregular or not in time.

Comment: Recenlty I have experienced the same issue. Did you happen to fix this? Or maybe have some clues why this happens?

Comment: No,I haven't met this for quite a long time, but I met this again a few days ago.I'm still searching for some clues but hasn't found any...what an  annoying problem!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be too late for an answer but still just for the future reference.

I had the same problem. I was setting keep alive timer when app went to background.

The problem is that sometimes voip app starts in background and thus my timer setting in `applicationDidEnterBackground` code was never called and app was just going to sleep after some period.

So I have added this code to app did finish launching.

```
// in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {    
    [self setupKeepAliveTimer:application]; // setup timer as you need
}
```

I hope that helps someone.