# ios voip socket run in background,after 9min,SIGSTOP sigal recevied. Why?

Tags: ios, sockets, background, voip

client :in  plist file 
Required background modes:

```
[App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay,App provides Voice over IP services]
```

in function **createStream**

```
 CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
```

in function **applicationDidEnterBackground**

```
BOOL backgroundAccepted = [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
    [self send:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ KeepAliveTimeout",[NSDate date]]];
}];
if (backgroundAccepted)
{
    DLog(@"VOIP background");
}
_bgTaskId=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [self alert:@"ExpirationHandler"];
    [application endBackgroundTask:_bgTaskId];
    _bgTaskId=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

in function  `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
[application clearKeepAliveTimeout];
```

server send message to client every 5 senconds with NSTimer.client app use local notification to show message in background immediately;

Answer (score 0):

If your app dose wake up more than 15 times in a 300 seconds interval is going to be killed.
if you send a message to the app every 5 second and process this message then i am surprised that your app runs for 9 minutes.

Have a look here: [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746599/setkeepalivetimeout-ios-behavior-exceeded-15-wakes-in-300-sec) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787202/voip-app-is-not-wake-up-in-time-if-set-15-min-for-setkeepalivetimeout-method)

Answer (score 0):

I have go through exactly problem like you, all you have to do is remove the code

```
_bgTaskId=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [self alert:@"ExpirationHandler"];
    [application endBackgroundTask:_bgTaskId];
    _bgTaskId=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

I have try it several times, If you call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, your application will be terminate by system anyway.

and just keep the code 
    BOOL backgroundAccepted = [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
        [self send:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ KeepAliveTimeout",[NSDate date]]];
        //unless you have more job to do here.
    }];
    if (backgroundAccepted)
    {
        DLog(@"VOIP background");
    }

From the result I can see, If you already keep the right handle for Socket, Your handle code will be call automatically, just like you are in the foreground.